# ValueError, even if doesn't have any active mentions

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a forum application written entirely in Django, but whenever I try to visit a topic of an user without avatar (I don't want to make it necessary), it throws ValueError. I've tried to comment every mention of avatars on template, but it still doesn't work.

**topic.html (template)**

```html
{% for post in posts %}
<div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="d-flex col mt-0 text-white" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to right, darkblue , blue);">
                    {{ topic.titleName }}
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex col bg-secondary">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3 border-right border-light">
                            <!--img src="{{post.author.avatar.url|default:"user_avatars/None/placeholder.jpg"}}" alt=" " class="avatar-forum rounded-circle"-->
                            <br>
                            {{ post.author }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <div class="d-flex col">
                                Przez:{{post.author}} >> {{ post.created_date }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-flex col">
                              {{ post.postData }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

**views.py - view of standalone topic**

```py
def RBFTopic(request, slug):
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, titleSlug = slug)
    posts_list = Post.objects.filter(topic = topic.pk)
    paginator = Paginator(posts_list, 20)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'topic.html', {'topic': topic, 'posts':posts})
```

**models.py**

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_avatars/', default = 'user_avatars/None/placeholder.jpg')
    is_blocked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.profile.save()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
...

#Model of forum topic
class Topic(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile,null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    titleCat = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    titleName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    titleSlug =  models.SlugField()
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            # Newly created object, so set slug
            self.titleSlug = slugify(self.titleName)

        super(Topic, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.titleName

#Model of forum post
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile,null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    postData = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

**Traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/retrobaza/topic/x

Django Version: 2.1.7
Python Version: 3.7.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'retrobaza']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template D:\ZPW\mysite\retrobaza\templates\base.html, error at line 11
   The 'avatar' attribute has no file associated with it.
   1 : {% load static %}
   2 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   3 : <html>
   4 : <head>
   5 : <title>RetroBaza.pl</title>
   6 : <meta charset="UTF-8">
   7 : <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|VT323" rel="stylesheet">
   8 : <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles/basestyle.css' %}">
   9 : <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
   10 : <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   11 : <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/ popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clH TMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   12 : <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   13 : </head>
   14 : <body>
   15 : <div class="pageHeader">
   16 :     <div class="title">
   17 :         <h1><a href="{% url 'retrobaza-index' %}">RetroBaza-Nowe miejsce dla starych maszyn</a></h1>
   18 :     </div>
   19 :         <nav class="mb-1 navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark default-color ">
   20 :         <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'retrobaza-index' %}">RetroBaza</a>
   21 :         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent-333"


Traceback:

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  829.                     current = current[bit]

During handling of the above exception ('ImageFieldFile' object is not subscriptable), another exception occurred:

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\ZPW\mysite\retrobaza\views.py" in RBFTopic
  70.     return render(request, 'topic.html', {'topic': topic, 'posts':posts})

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  209.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  987.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  671.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  796.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  837.                         current = getattr(current, bit)

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in url
  61.         self._require_file()

File "D:\ZPW\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in _require_file
  38.             raise ValueError("The '%s' attribute has no file associated with it." % self.field.name)

Exception Type: ValueError at /retrobaza/topic/x
Exception Value: The 'avatar' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

Comment: can you post the whole traceback?

Comment: Also we probably need the code that is sending information to the template (populating the posts object in your template)

Comment: Commenting out in HTML won't stop the template tags from needing to be rendered. If you really want to comment it out you need to use Django comment tags: `{# ... #}` or `{% comment %}...{% endcomment %}`.

Comment: Added view, and post + topic model for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are accessing the `url` attribute of the `avatar` field without making sure is not null:

```html
<img src={{post.author.avatar.url|default:"user_avatars/None/placeholder.jpg"}}" alt=" " class="avatar-forum rounded-circle">
```

Do this instead:

```html
{% if post.author.avatar %}
  <img src="{{ post.author.avatar.url }}" alt=" " class="avatar-forum rounded-circle">
{% else %}
  <img src="user_avatars/None/placeholder.jpg" alt=" " class="avatar-forum rounded-circle">
{% endif %}
```